# MVP - не отображаются данные во View

Tags: java, android, mvp

Делаю проект согласно паттерна MVP и столкнулась с проблемой, что данные не отображаются во View. Что я делаю неправильно? В чем может быть проблема? Я так понимаю, что возможно, что-то неправильно с презентером.

класс BasePresenter:

```
public abstract class  BasePresenter<V> {

    protected V view;
    private CompositeSubscription compositeSubscription=new CompositeSubscription();

    public void bindView(V view){
        this.view=view;
    }

    public void unBindView(){
        this.view=null;
        compositeSubscription.clear();
    }

    protected void addSubscription(Subscription subscription){
        compositeSubscription.add(subscription);
    }
}
```

Класс PresenterFactory:

```
public class PresenterFactory {

    private final BaseApi baseApi;
    private static PresenterFactory presenterFactory;
    private PresenterFactory(BaseApi baseApi) {
        this.baseApi = baseApi;
    }
    public static void create(BaseApi baseApi){
        if(presenterFactory ==null){
            presenterFactory =new PresenterFactory(baseApi);
        }
    }
    public static PresenterFactory getInstance() {
        return presenterFactory;
    }
    public BasePresenter get(String tag) {
        if (tag.equals(ContactPresenter.TAG)) {
            return new ContactPresenter(baseApi);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Класс `ContactPresenter`:

```
 public class ContactPresenter extends BasePresenter<ContactView> {

        public static final String TAG = ContactPresenter.class.getName();

        BaseApi baseApi;
        private ArrayList<User> contacts;
        private ArrayList<Users> usersList;
        ContactAdapter contactAdapter;

        public ContactPresenter(BaseApi baseApi) {
            this.baseApi = baseApi;
            contacts=new ArrayList<>();
            usersList=new ArrayList<> ();
        }

        public void onCreate(){
            getUsers();

        }

        private void getUsers() {
            Subscription subscription = BaseApi.getInstance().service.users()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(users -> {
                        usersList.add(users);
for (int i = 0; i < usersList.size(); i++) {
                        contacts.addAll(usersList.get(i).getUser());
                        );
                    }

                    }, throwable -> {
                        Log.e("User errors", String.valueOf(throwable));
                    });

            addSubscription(subscription);
        }
    }
```

Интерфейс ContactView:

```
public interface ContactView {
    void showData(ArrayList<User> contacts);
}
```

Класс App:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        PresenterFactory.create(BaseApi.getInstance());
    }
}
```

Фрагмент в котором используется презентер:

```
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment implements ContactView {

    private ArrayList<User> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Users> usersList = new ArrayList<>();

    private ContactAdapter contactAdapter;
    private RecyclerView rvView;
    private ContactPresenter mPresenter;
    private CompositeSubscription compositeSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();
    public ContactFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
        rvView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvView);

        mPresenter = (ContactPresenter) PresenterFactory.getInstance().get(ContactPresenter.TAG);
        mPresenter.bindView(this);

        contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(contacts, new OnItemClickListenerUser() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(User user) {

            }
        });


        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        rvView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        rvView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
        contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mPresenter.unBindView();
    }

    @Override
    public void showData(ArrayList<User> contacts) {
        this.contacts.addAll(contacts);
        contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну во первых, ваше презентер начинает загружать данные своем методе `onCreate`, который никто не вызывает, а сам он не вызовется.
Во вторых, даже если бы его кто-то вызвал, то данные все равно бы не отобразились, т.к. ваш `Observer` только добавляет данные в списки, но не вызывает метод `view`, который бы отобразил эти данные.

Поэтому в метод subscribe добавьте `view.showData(contacts)`, и вызовите `mPresenter.onCreate()` например в `onCreaeView`

Comment: Попробовала только что, метод showData() отрабатывает, но когда пытаюсь вывести в лог ArrayList<User> contacts в showData(), то получается, что этот массив пустой.

Comment: @Lucky_girl ну это уже другой вопрос, который никакого отношения к mvp не имеет. Посмотрите свой код ещё раз повнимательней, возможно найдете причину.